# How to check the value of IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn about transactions, but I don't know how to check if I've been working with IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS on or off.

Is this set to OFF by default, and how do I check what the current value is?

Comment: `DBCC USEROPTIONS` will list the `SET` options in effect for the current session.

Comment: Did you research this? The first google hit on IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 which in turn has a section entitled "To view the current setting for IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, run the following query"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set implicit transaction on/off

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF/ON
```

Get if implicit transaction on or off

```
select IIF(@@OPTIONS & 2 = 0, 'OFF', 'ON')
```

By default it is OFF.

Comment: Or, necessary for versions before 2012: `SELECT CASE @@OPTIONS & 2 WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR SQL SERVER 2022**

for sql server 2022 we can use GET_BIT() function

```
SELECT GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 1)  /* 2 */ AS [IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS]
```

link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/get-bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

and for complete list use below query

```
SELECT
      GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 0)  /* 1     */ AS [DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK] -- Controls interim or deferred constraint checking.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 1)  /* 2     */ AS [IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS] -- For dblib network library connections, controls whether a transaction is started implicitly when a statement is executed. The IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS setting has no effect on ODBC or OLEDB connections.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 2)  /* 4     */ AS [CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT] -- Controls behavior of cursors after a commit operation has been performed.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 3)  /* 8     */ AS [ANSI_WARNINGS] -- Controls truncation and NULL in aggregate warnings.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 4)  /* 16    */ AS [ANSI_PADDING] -- Controls padding of fixed-length variables.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 5)  /* 32    */ AS [ANSI_NULLS] -- Controls NULL handling when using equality operators.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 6)  /* 64    */ AS [ARITHABORT] -- Terminates a query when an overflow or divide-by-zero error occurs during query execution.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 7)  /* 128   */ AS [ARITHIGNORE] -- Returns NULL when an overflow or divide-by-zero error occurs during a query.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 8)  /* 256   */ AS [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER] -- Differentiates between single and double quotation marks when evaluating an expression.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 9)  /* 512   */ AS [NOCOUNT] -- Turns off the message returned at the end of each statement that states how many rows were affected.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 10) /* 1024  */ AS [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON] -- Alters the session's behavior to use ANSI compatibility for nullability. New columns defined without explicit nullability are defined to allow nulls.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 11) /* 2048  */ AS [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF] -- Alters the session's behavior not to use ANSI compatibility for nullability. New columns defined without explicit nullability do not allow nulls.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 12) /* 4096  */ AS [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL] -- Returns NULL when concatenating a NULL value with a string.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 13) /* 8192  */ AS [NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT] -- Generates an error when a loss of precision occurs in an expression.
    , GET_BIT(@@OPTIONS, 14) /* 16384 */ AS [XACT_ABORT] -- Rolls back a transaction if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.*/
GO
```